# systemdのタイミングの書き方

Tags: systemd

Debian の起動時にアプリを自動実行しようとしています。

テスト時に、端末からは自動実行できるアプリですが、systemdのサービスを作り、
起動時に立ち上げようとすると、起動できず、syslogに

```
Could not connect to any X display.
```

とのエラーが記録されています。
Xサーバの起動完了する前に、アプリを起動しようとして、エラーになっているかと思うのですが

systemdで、Xorgが起動した後、または通常のシステム起動シーケンスが終了した後に
サービスを起動するには、どのよな条件を書けば良いでしょうか？

.serviceの内容です

```
[Unit]
Description=Exec my_application
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/myapp_start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After=の部分をどう書けば良いか分かりません。

Comment: エラー内容としては環境変数 DISPLAY が適切に設定されていないため、な場合も考えられます。 / 単にアプリを自動起動させたいだけなら、サービスとしてではなく `xinitrc` を利用することも選択肢の一つです。 / 敢えてsystemdからの起動を実現したいということであれば、想定しているアプリや、作成したUnitファイルの内容についての情報もあると回答の参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: 良く分からないまま、~/.xinitrc を #!/bin/sh /usr/local/bin/myapp と書いて作ってみたんですが、起動できませんでした。